# I am not sure how to create and pass a context

Tags: http, go, grpc

I have an HTTP server that when it recieves a request calls on an underlying gRPC server.

I have chosen to abstract away the gRPC call with an interface, to make testing of the http server easier.

The problem is that I am constantly getting the errors:
`rpc error: code = Canceled desc = grpc: the client connection is closing`
or
`rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

And as I understand both of these are related to the context getting passed into the grpc call. And that I want the context to be alive throughout both the HTTP and gRPC calls.

```
type SetterGetter interface {
    Getter(key string) (val string)
}
type Service struct {
    sg  SetterGetter
    ctx context.Context
}

func (s *Service) getHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    key := r.URL.Query()["key"][0]
    res := s.sg.Getter(key)
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Successfully got value: %s\n", res)
}

func main() {
    s := new(Service)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    s.sg = gc.NewClientwrapper(ctx)

    http.HandleFunc("/get", s.getHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))
}
```

And my Getter implementation looks like this:

```
type clientwrapper struct {
    sc  pb.ServicesClient
    ctx context.Context
}

func NewClientwrapper(ctx context.Context) *clientwrapper {
    cw := new(clientwrapper)

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Error could not dial address: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    cw.ctx = ctx

    cw.sc = pb.NewServicesClient(conn)

    return cw
}

func (cw *clientwrapper) Getter(key string) (val string) {
    // Make the GRPC request
    res, err := cw.sc.Get(cw.ctx, &pb.GetRequest{Key: key})
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    getVal := res.GetValue()
    return getVal 
}
```

So here I am creating a context in my http servers main menu, and passing it onwards. I do it like this because it worked if I removed my interface and put everything in the main file.

I have also tried to create the context both in the http handler and passing it to the `Getter` and I have also tried creating it in the `Getter` itself.

I think the correct approach is to create the context in the http request using the context that gets created by the request and then passing it to the grpc `Getter`. Like such:

```
func (s *Service) getHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   

    // Create it like such
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), 100*time.Second)

    key := r.URL.Query()["key"][0]
    // And pass it onwards (of course we need to change function signature for this to work)
    res := s.sg.Getter(ctx, key)
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Successfully got value: %s\n", res)
}
```

So how should I create my context here, to not get these errors?

Comment: You generally don't create a context for HTTP requests. One is created automatically for each request, and accessible via the [Context()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) method on the request.

Comment: The only time you create your own context, is if you need some operation _not_ to be scoped to the request. That is to say, if the request is cancelled, you want the operation to complete anyway (i.e. when doing something in the background that may continue after responding to the request)

Comment: @Flimzy Yea, I created a new sub-context with the context from the request. As you can see in the last code snippet. I have also tried passing the http context directly as well. But with no success.

Comment: So what is the problem you need to solve? Those errors indicate that the context has been cancelled. That's probably not a problem, if you have cancelable contexts for a reason (I assume you have a reason to put them there).

Comment: @FelixRosén aren't *you* explicitly setting the context timeout to 10 seconds? How long is your server supposed to run? Less than that? Or am I just misreading the code in main?

Comment: @Flimzy I want to keep it alive so that It can fetch some data from the gRPC server. Now it can not do that. It simply gets this error directly. Is the correct way to propagate the http context all the way to the grpc server in this case? (I have tried it, but can try it again)

Comment: Then you need to createa a new context. Use `context.Background()`. Don't use the existing one, which will cancel as soon as the request is served.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes you are seeing correct. If I dont put a large number there I used to get grpc closing errors when it was working (when I had everything in the same file and no interface)

Comment: @Flimzy Like im doing in the last code snippet, but with `context.background()` instead of `r.context()`?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you want a 100-second timeout.

Comment: Get rid of the ctx field. I think that's what confuses you. Use r.Context() for the RPC. Wrapping *that one* with WithTimeout is fine, but wrapping a background context makes no sense in a server that is supposed to run forever.

Comment: @Flimzy When I do that I still get a `rpc error: code = Canceled desc = grpc: the client connection is closing`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a context-related error message.

Comment: @Peter So what you are saying is to do what I do in the last code snippet? Or what do you mean? I still get my error doing that!

Comment: "wrapping a background context makes no sense in a server that is supposed to run forever." -- That's not always true.

Comment: @Flimzy I think you are corret. Removing the `defer conn.Close()` connection makes it work! So its about my connection closing before I can even make my call. Thanks

Comment: @Flimzy I can accept an answer with this, if you want to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to keep a long-running task running in the background, that doesn't cancel when the request is finalized, then don't use the request's context.  Use `context.Background()` instead.

For example:

```golang
func (s *Service) getHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
    // ...
```

Comment: Also to add, the error I had was not related to contexts but that I was closing my connection to fast (remove `defer conn.Close()` in this case, not sure if its good to do this though). And you probably dont need to multiply time.Second with 100.